# How to transfer money more cheaply from Hong Kong to Canada, without HSBC?

Tags: canada, international-transfer, hong-kong

I live in Toronto, Canada.

About every 2 months, with HSBC's "Global Transfers" tool, I used to send myself money from my HSBC account in Hong Kong to my HSBC account in Canada.

Because I now need to abandon HSBC, how else can I do this **as or more cheaply**? I already know about regular wire transfers or money orders, but these seem more expensive than HSBC's options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are peer to peer services these days which work by trying to match someone who wants to convert currency X to currency Y with other people who want to convert Y to X. Obviously this works better with major currencies.

They tend to give you the midmarket interbank rate banks use to trade with each  less their commission of 1-2%. Banks can charge up to 5% and use different rates for buying and selling. Transfers may take a day or two, although you may be able to do it faster if you pay extra.

[Transferwise](https://transferwise.com/), [CurrencyFair](https://www.currencyfair.com/) and [MidPoint](https://www.midpoint.com/Articles/Midpoint-Concept) are examples of such services though there are many others.

Here's a link to a [newspaper article](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/expat-money/11226294/Peer-to-peer-exchange-firms-cut-out-the-banks-and-brokers.html) with more details.